# Can we register an existing site collection as a Hub site

Tags: development, pnp-powershell, hub-site

I am reading this official Microsoft documentation [SharePoint classic and modern experiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f), which mentioned that there is **not** a 1:1 map between site collections and hub sites, and we can not move a site collection to a hub site:-

> There is not a 1:1 mapping between site collections and hub sites, so
>   you can't automatically move a site collection to a hub site.

But on the other hand, there is another Microsoft official documentation, which mention how we can register a site collection as a hub site [Register-SPOHubSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/register-spohubsite?view=sharepoint-ps).
so i got confused..So if we have a site collection (modern or classic) which contain data and lists, can we define it as a hub site?, that other site collections can link to? as the info in the above 2 links is confusing, unless i did not understand it well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can convert any existing site to a hub site, [refer this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/create-hub-site-with-powershell)
I was able to create a classic site, register it as a hub site. Then create a modern communication site and associate it to this hub site.

Comment: and this what i know,, but not sure what is meant by `There is not a 1:1 mapping between site collections and hub sites, so you can't automatically move a site collection to a hub site.` inside MS official docs? as it made me confused...

Answer (score 2):

We can register an existing site collection as a Hub site.

Note: Sites that are already associated with another hub can't be converted to a hub site. Make sure the site is not associated with another hub.

We can create up to 100 hub sites for an organization.

Create a hub site in SharePoint Online for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-hub-site

Comment: so not sure what is meant by `There is not a 1:1 mapping between site collections and hub sites, so you can't automatically move a site collection to a hub site.` inside MS official docs?

Comment: What it means is "There is no limit on the number of sites that can be associated with a hub site.  Sites that are already associated with another hub can't be converted to a hub site."

Comment: Is there anything update?